# Create new table using WITH clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

Is it possible to create a table based on a query that is using WITH clause?

The query:

```
with test as (
  select 999 as col1
)
select * from test;
```

I tried :

```
select * into newtable from
(
  with test as(
    select 999 as col1
  )
  select * from test
) as newtable
```

But I get this error:

> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an
> xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause

NOTE: My real query is more complex so I cannot remove the WITH clause.

Comment: Just use the normal `select * into table from ...` syntax. FYI `WITH` is a CTE or Common Table Expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stuff a CTE inside a subquery like you're trying to do. Rather the insert syntax should be:

```
with test as (
  select 999 as col1
)

select *
into newtable
from test;
```